# update database queue with lock and ordered output

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a database queue existing of two tables, meta and data. A storec proc locks 100 rows, updates the status of the rows and returns meta + data. I have a windows service executing the stored proc.

The stored proc

```
update top(100) QueueMeta WITH (UPDLOCK, READPAST)
SET Status = 'processing'
OUTPUT inserted.Id, 
        inserted.CreatedOn, 
        inserted.Timeout, 
        qd.Message,
        qd.Msisdn,
        inserted.NrOfRetries,
        inserted.MaxNrOfRetries             

FROM QueueMeta qm
INNER JOIN QueueData qd
    ON qm.Id = qd.QueueMetaId
WHERE Status = 'readytosend' and SendOn <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

The thing is that I need to order this on QueueMeta.Prio (int). How should I proceed since order by is not allowed? Thinking of #Temp but I need the same functionality, as I have two different services that polls the database at the same time without losing performance. Any suggestions?

/Mike

Comment: Depending on your needs, you can use sql servers own locking mechanism "sp_getapplock" to serialize access to your critical section or stored procedure.

Comment: What order is the data coming back in now? It should be the primary key order. Maybe show us the table definitions as well.

Comment: By definition the order is unpredictable because there is no order by.

Comment: It doesnt matter really, I need to order by Prio ( an int on the meta table) and its not a primary key.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can use a table-typed variable to select into with the capability of ordering. Also note that you must use (UPDLOCK, READPAST) hints in the from clause to avoid concurrent updates which, if occurring, will mutate the state of selected records.

```
DECLARE @Dequeued TABLE (
    Id BIGINT/INT PRIMARY KEY,
)

INSERT INTO @Dequeued
SELECT TOP (100)
    Id
FROM QueueMeta WITH (UPDLOCK, READPAST)
WHERE
    Status = 'readytosend' AND
    SendOn <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
ORDER BY Prio DESC

UPDATE qm
SET
    Status = 'processing'
OUTPUT
    INSERTED.Id, 
    INSERTED.CreatedOn, 
    INSERTED.Timeout, 
    qd.Message,
    qd.Msisdn,
    INSERTED.NrOfRetries,
    INSERTED.MaxNrOfRetries
FROM QueueMeta qm
INNER JOIN @Dequeued d
    ON d.Id = qm.Id
INNER JOIN QueueData qd
    ON qd.QueueMetaId = qm.Id
```

Good to mention: Define an index on the columns Status, SendOn and Prio if not defined already.