Will using a transaction on my SQL Server prevent another host from being able to read rows in the table?
Suppose I have a table that is constantly being updated with tasks to be processed. One column in this table is Status, and when a task is first entered into the table, Status = 'submitted'. When a host is processing the task, it changes Status to 'processing', and when the data processing for the task has been completed, it updates Status to 'completed'.
I will have multiple hosts that will be accessing this specific table to check to see if a task has been added.
This is the code that I currently have:
conn = get_mssql_conn().connect()

result = conn.execute(
                    "SELECT TOP 1 * "
                    "FROM ad_tool_enhancement "
                    "WHERE status = 'submitted' "
                    "ORDER BY jobid ASC" 
                    )

row = result.fetchall()
   
if row:
    jobid, Job_name, Email, status, date_submit, time_submit, process_time, json_data, Input, analysis_type, source, groupby = row[0]

    start = datetime.datetime.now()

    conn.execute(f"UPDATE ad_tool_enhancement "
                f"SET status = 'processing' "
                f"WHERE jobid = {jobid}"
                )
    
    #Then the task is processed                

This works fine for when there is only one host running/processing the tasks, but in the future there will be more and I believe that I will need to use locks/transactions to ensure that two hosts do not start processing the same task at the same time.
Where I am confused is that I have never seen a transaction used for a read statement (and that part is just as important as the update part for locking) so I am not sure if it will work.
I have tried looking at the documentation for SQL Alchemy and for MS SQL Server but I have not found anything specific to my problem.

Transaction by itself... no... I would suggest using a stored procedure so you can run all your SQL in one request. You need to have a look around, you might be able to do a single update statement using the output clause.

I think this is what you need https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28201645/update-database-queue-with-lock-and-ordered-output (which personally I would do inside a SP so you can performance tune as necessary without needing to change your code every time).

As it stands, your code contains a race condition. There is nothing to stop multiple workers picking up the same row; you need an update lock or hold lock on the SELECT. You are trying to implement your own queue inside SQL Server, and there are subtleties. why not use an open source queue ?

Also, lookup READPAST

@MitchWheat Because I do not know how to use an open source queue

All statements implicitly run in their own transaction anyway. A queue is best implemented using a single UPDATE with an OUTPUT eg UPDATE top (1) ad_tool_enhancement WITH (READPAST) SET status = 'processing' OUTPUT inserted.jobid WHERE status = 'submitted' ORDER BY jobid ASC; you also need a clustered index on jobid otherwise your locking will jam up the whole table while you are busy scanning it all.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177880/using-a-database-table-as-a-queue , https://www.rabbitmq.com/

@Charlieface while i don't disagree with your statement, order by isn't possible in straight update

@siggemannen Sorry you're right needs to be in a CTE WITH cte AS (SELECT TOP (1) * FROM ad_tool_enhancement WITH (READPAST) WHERE status = 'submitted' ORDER BY jobid ASC) UPDATE cte SET status = 'processing' OUTPUT inserted.jobid;
